# Webpack including its own dependencies in bundle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I am fairly new to webpack and I have a Vue project using the `vue cli`. While analyzing the webpack bundle (built in production mode using `vue-cli-service build`) using `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, I found that one particular file `bn.js` is being included multiple times in the bundle. When running `npm ls bn.js` I found that it's parent dependency is `webpack` itself.

```
`-- webpack@4.44.1
  `-- node-libs-browser@2.2.1
    `-- crypto-browserify@3.12.0
      +-- browserify-sign@4.2.1
      | +-- bn.js@5.1.3
      | +-- browserify-rsa@4.0.1
      | | `-- bn.js@4.11.9
      | +-- elliptic@6.5.3
      | | `-- bn.js@4.11.9
      | `-- parse-asn1@5.1.6
      |   `-- asn1.js@5.4.1
      |     `-- bn.js@4.11.9
      +-- create-ecdh@4.0.4
      | `-- bn.js@4.11.9
      +-- diffie-hellman@5.0.3
      | +-- bn.js@4.11.9
      | `-- miller-rabin@4.0.1
      |   `-- bn.js@4.11.9
      `-- public-encrypt@4.0.3
        `-- bn.js@4.11.9
```

So my question is that why is webpack including it's own dependencies in the final bundle when webpack is added as a devDependency (earlier it was a dependency, then I changed it to devDepenency) in the project?

Or if this is the correct behavior then please point me to any docs/resources explaining this behavior.

Comment: I had this problem due to importing -- directly, and by using node packages that indirectly imported -- nodes `crypto` module.  It was a bear to get rid of, since I didn't really find a way to trace which dependency was responsible.  it was a lot of trial an error.  eventually I replaced everything that required `crypto` with browser friendly version.  Thanks to `tweetnacl` and `jsrsasign` @kjur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out that it was a npm thing. Earlier I had webpack as a dependency in `package.json`. Then I ran `npm uninstall webpack --save` and then again did `npm install webpack --save-dev` in order to make it a dev dependency. Turns out that it wasnt enough. I stopped getting webpack dependencies in my bundle only after I deleted my node_modules folder and then did npm install again.

Answer (score 1):

A tip for how I found which framework was the problem. In Webpack configs I set {node: false} and then I built the production code. Webpack should flag the offending framework. This can be a problem for code that was originally written for the server side and expects certain packages to be available and do not show up on package-lock.json.

If you're using something like create-react-app, then you can use a framework like react-app-rewired to customize the Webpack configs.

Happy unused code busting!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue where I was unable to find why a library called bn.js, elliptic etc. were being imported.

Turns out, it was because we were using a library called `[generate-password][1]` that was [importing `crypto`](https://github.com/brendanashworth/generate-password/blob/master/src/generate.js#L1) and because of that I was seeing multiple modules that I never imported. Have a look at this image below.

[image: Many instances of bn.js and elliptic]

If you ever find yourself in such a situation where you can't find the import statements for a particular library in your codebase, just do:

```sh
npm ls libname
```

[image: Result of npm ls on the library name]

There are cases where there are some libraries that are importing these methods internally and therefore, causing your vendor bundle to bloat.
In the case of `generate-password`, it was importing the crypto module from node. The whole module ended up in the vendor bundle because `generate-password` was using one function from the crypto module.

How I avoided importing crypto:

1. Copied the generate-password source code into my codebase as a util.
2. Replaced the randomBytes function from crypto lib with a specific [npm version of the randomBytes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randombytes).
3. Remove node_modules and rebuild using yarn/npm.